# Shell script and adding large values in a delimited file

Tags: awk, sh, csv

I have a script that reads through a delimited file and adds up the 3rd element in the file for each record. For a majority of the data files, this works fine except for one. I have one data file were there are 193 records in the data file. I am expecting to get 2028219.43 back from the script. Instead, I get an exponential number back which appears to have been rounded up. At first I thought that by using printf I will get the number but if the number has already been rounded, then it's not going to give me back what I am expecting.

This is the code that I am using to read the delimited datafile. The data in each record is delimited by an *.:

```
export clm_total=$( awk -F* '{f1+=$3} END {print f1}' datafile.dat)
export new_clm_total=$(printf "%.2f" $clm_total)
```

This is what shows up in the log when I run the script:

```
+ export clm_total=2.02822e+06
+ printf %.2f 2.02822e+06
+ export new_clm_total=2028220.00
+ echo 2028220.00
```

This is a sample of the data file. There are more records, I didn't didn't think it was necessary to display all 193 records:

```
CLM*123456789*4820.9***13:A:1**A*Y*Y
CLM*123698547*3642.05***13:A:7**A*Y*Y
CLM*147852369*579.25***13:A:1**A*Y*Y
CLM*789654123*929.8***13:A:1**A*Y*Y
```

What I am expecting back is 2028219.43

What I am getting back is 2.02822e+06

Which then gets formatted as 2028220.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the right track with printf (or CONVFMT) but you're calling printf AFTER the numbers been converted. Just do it in your awk script:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print 2028219.43 }'           
2.02822e+06
$ awk 'BEGIN{ printf "%.2f\n", 2028219.43 }'
2028219.43
```

Comment: THanks! I used this and it works:  export clm_total=$( awk -F* '{f1+=$3} END{printf ("%.2f\n",f1)}' datafile.dat)

Comment: If this is the answer you wanted, please click on the check mark next to it.